# Change Photo Resolution

Tags: settings, nokia-lumia-920, camera, pictures

Is there a way to change the photo resolution in Windows Phone 8? Specifically I have a Nokia Lumia 920.

The 920 takes pictures at 8.7 megapixels with an image size of 3264 x 2448 pixels. For most of my needs, that's too much. I can do with half that size, say 1632 x 1224 pixels which would be 2.2 megapixels.

I can't see any way to change the settings. Is there no way, or am I missing something?

Comment: This is not really a solution but a workaround: upload imaes to SkyDrive over your data plan. SkyDrive will shrink the quality and emailing will do the same.

Comment: @karancan - That's an idea. But almost every camera and Android phone allows you to set the resolution prior to taking the photos. You'd think Windows Phone would have thought to include this ability.

Comment: I agree. I think this is one of those things where MS is really trying to clear up the interface for all their platforms and by doing so some flexibility is lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get yourself a copy of Proshot from the app store and use it to drive the camera and that will allow you to set the image size as well as load of other features... sizes go from 640 by 480 (.3MP) up to 3246 by 2448.

Answer (score 4):

When the camera is running, use the cog icon in the app bar to bring up the menu.  Scroll about half way through and you should see **Resolution** with the current option.  Tap that and you can change the resolution.

Comment: I just tried this on my Lumia 920 and I don't have this option.

Comment: I don't have a 920, as they still haven't got any stock near me, but that option was as tested on a HTC running 7.8

Comment: Doesn't work on my 920, no option for it, but when I borrowed my son's HTC 8x, it does have a resolution option. that ranges from 8M (3264x2448) down to VGA (640x480). Maybe Nokia will implement it at some point.

Answer (score 2):

This option is apparently missing in <strike>Windows Phone 8</strike> the Lumia 920. Switching to 4:3 will make the image even bigger, so that's not a solution either.

It is possible that this option will make a return in a future update.

Comment: It's there on the 8x

Comment: interesting. I changed my answer accordingly.